# Missing return statement in Java/Kmax

Tags: java, compiler-errors, return

I am writing  a Data Acquisition Software using Sparrow's platform [Kmax](http://www.sparrowcorp.com/products/software). This platform has it's own classes and methods, that one has to have worked with it to be familiar. I am trying to make a checkbox button to do a job. To do that, I need to convert a string `1` or `0` to boolean `true` or `false` respectively. For this task I built the simple method that follows

```
public static boolean stringToBool(String s) {
        if (s.equals("1"))
            return true;
        if (s.equals("0"))
            return false;
  }
```

When I am trying to compile it I get an error

> `Runtime.java:30: error: missing return statement }`

Note that line 30 is the last line(i.e. } ) of the previous code.

I don't see any point on what could be wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: What if `s` isn't `"1"` or `"0"`?

Answer (score 4):

Say those cases aren't true (that `s` is not equal to `"1"` or `"0"`), then what? You must `return` a default value at the end (which doesn't seem to be a good idea for your code if you are only expecting those two values) or `throw` an `Exception`:

```
public static boolean stringToBool(String s) {
        if (s.equals("1")){
            return true;
        }
        if (s.equals("0")){
            return false;
        }
        throw new Exception("0 or 1 Required");
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Actually I cannot throw an exception, because I will use this method as a converter in another method, sth like `widget.getProperty(stringToBool("VALUE"))`

Comment: @Thanos: That doesn't mean you can't throw an exception. It depends entirely on how you want to treat input that isn't `"1"` or `"0"`.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to throw an Exception if you handle it properly.  If you know that `widget.getProperty(stringToBool("VALUE"))` will only ever return `"1"` or `"0"`, then this is a good way to go.  The Exception will only be thrown if your value is not equal to `"1"` or `"0"`.

Comment: You are right! Why is an Exception better that a return command? I believe that because it will be a dummy command, it won't matter in this case, so I am asking in general!

Comment: Exceptions can be good or bad.  Throwing an Exception will cause your program to "crash".  However, that's assuming it will reach that line...and that's assuming you don't handle the Exception somewhere else.  In this case, it's good to throw the Exception because if `s` isn't `"0"` or `"1"`, then you know something went wrong in the code/data/user input/etc.  You want to throw the Exception right there and then instead of it affecting you badly later down the road

Answer (score 2):

There needs to be a `return` statement executed in all cases, but you don't have a return statement if both `if` statements are `false`.

Provide a default case at the end:

```
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You are right! Adding a `return` after the `if` statements really works. Thank's a lot!

Comment: I think by default he should be returning false.

Comment: @CodeBlue It depends on how things like `""`, `"-1"`, and `"Hello world!"` are to be interpreted.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler does not know that your String will always be "1" or "0". Therefore, as a safety measure, it ensures that you are required to return some value (although you may never actually return it in practice).

I suggest you return false by default.

```
public static boolean stringToBool(String s) {
        if (s.equals("1")){
            return true;}
        if (s.equals("0")){
            return false;}

        return false;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have a question though. Why false and not true? The thing is that I am creating values 1 and 0 so there isn't any chance at all to have something different. Also  I will use this method as a converter in another method, sth like `widget.getProperty(stringToBool("VALUE"))`

Comment: As, rgettman also mentioned, it depends on how you interpret "true" or "false". In your case, if you are doing more important stuff if a statement is true, it would make sense to return false by default.

Comment: They are equally important! So I suppose it doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: Then it does not matter, however, to be absolutely safe, you should throw an exception as was also suggested here.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options. You code cannot compile because your code must have a return statement always, but, when you put it within the if statemens the compiler cannot find a return for every possible execution path.

```
   public static final String TRUE = "1";
   public static final String FALSE = "0"

   public static boolean stringToBool(String s) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (s.equals(TRUE)){
            return true;
        }
        return result;
    }


public static boolean stringToBool2(String s) {
    boolean result = false;

    switch(s) {
        case FALSE:
            result = false;
            break;
        case TRUE:
            result = true;
            break;
        default:
            // Uuups. Throw exception or return false
    }
    return result;
}
```